# Which Azure SDK for Node Mobile Service scripts is to be used / where is it documented?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

Being new to Azure I am confused about the azure sdk one adds to mobile service scripts via `require('azure');`

I want to get a blob and found this [git project](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node), which has nice [wrappers for the blob storage](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js).

I assumed this to be related to my required one. Yet, the required one returns a blob storage service object (`createBlobService`) that has methods like `createContainerIfNotExists` and `generateSharedAccessSignature`, but misses `**getBlob**` ( [documented here](http://documentup.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node#usage/blob-storage) ) among others, and has `**getBlobToStream**`.

So clearly the azure sdk I require in Node is something completely different from the github project or just not the same version of it.

**Questions:**

- where is the official documentation from Microsoft regarding what I get when I do `require('azure')` ?
- how would I make sure I have the most recent version ?
- if these are two different azure sdks, then is it recommended to replace the one I currently require with the github project mentioned above ?

Thanks

**Update**:

[This link](http://dl.windowsazure.com/nodedocs/BlobService.html) seems to be the official documentation. So in my specific case I am supposed to use getBlobToStream.

**At that point, my question comes down to**: how do I know which version of the azure sdk is currently deployed with my mobile service? The package.json does not list this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you install that by utilising npm and run the command:

```
npm install azure
```

which will pull the package down from https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure

Comment: Hi Simon. I suppose this is how I can get the SDK locally. But I am not sure how to deploy it to the Mobile Service and whether this is recommended at all. I got all code from the Mobile Service locally in a git repository via the service's source-control feature. But there is no node-modules folder at all.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation here to help: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-store-scripts-source-control/#use-npm

Comment: Thanks again Simon. That's the way how I added other modules such as uuid and stream-buffers. I guess I am confused as to why I do not see the azure-sdk here already. That's why I think it is different from the one in github. I just don't want to create a messy situation.